# Makefile: rebuild target if its source changes

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've got this Makefile in a PHP project (this is trimmed down from the full Makefile). How can I change this so automake detects that `public/assets/styles/main.scss` has changed & re-run sass?

```
all: public/assets/styles/styles.css

public/assets/styles/styles.css:
    sass public/assets/styles/main.scss > public/assets/styles/styles.css
```

Comment: You need to set the scss file as dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make the `.scss` file a prerequisite of your `.css` target. As a bonus, avoid repetition of your base path and use [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) to  make the recipe less redundant:

```
STYLEDIR := public/assets/styles

all: $(STYLEDIR)/styles.css

$(STYLEDIR)/styles.css: $(STYLEDIR)/main.scss
    sass $< > $@
```

Comment: Problem here: if the `sass` command fails, the output is still created. Will confuse _make_ on the next run. Add a `DELETE_ON_ERROR:` somewhere in the makefile (you nearly always want this enabled).